# Multiple databases with Django

Tags: django

I have about 6 target databases with their own Django admin data and application data. Right now, I am running 6 instances of the same Django application on different hosts. What I would like to do is run one instance of the app, but up front have the user select which database he wishes to connect. Where should I inject this new code so that it hits BEFORE it tries to read the Django.core admin code?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Yes, I saw that earlier. It appears this is more for dynamic changing of the database at runtime where you are using the different databases in a session. I'm looking for the case where you select one database up front, for the duration of the session until logging out.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Django specified database for admin only, then a redirect gets the 'factory' specified database name. The handler for this redirect manually connects to the correct database. I now have 4 separate remote databases with a local administrative database. Django itself doesn't really handle this internally, so this is a workaround.

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    factory = request.POST.get('factory', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/app/?factory={}".format(factory))
```